# when I update pom.xml, Intellij Idea is not updatingclasspath jars when running java program

Tags: intellij-idea

**1.below is idea commandline:**
C:\xxx\jdk-11.0.7\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:C:\xxx\JetBrains\IntelliJ Community Edition 2020.3.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=59400:C:\swdtools\JetBrains\IntelliJ Community Edition 2020.3.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 **@C:\Users\45229909\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_arg_file76175574** com.MainApp

when I click '**idea_arg_file76175574**' i can see redundant email jar like: 'spring-integration-mail-5.5.14.jar' and 'mail-1.4.jar'

but my pom.xml only have 'springboot-starter-mail' even when I use 'mvn dependency:tree' to show all dependencies.

I got this problem many times, when I remove a jar in pom.xml, it is not removed from idea, so when i run java process i still can see them....

**2.idea version**
Idea community 2020.3 (I have tried 2022, no use)

**4.infomation**

1.picture 1 is showed by 'mvn dependency:tree', only have **'springboot-start-mail'**

2.picture 2 is showed by click idea arg file, it have **spring-integration-mail** and **mail-1.4.jar**, i have removed this two dependency, don't know why they appeared in idea classpath

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ow2Ke.png)

[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJQ6C.png)

**action to try**
1.click 'maven' - > right click this project -> reload project   (no use)
2.mvn clear install (no use)
3.restart idea (no use)
4.remove this project from maven + clear idea cache and restart + reimport maven project  (worked)

**expect**:
how to keep idea classpath with pom.xml when i update pom.xml? i don't want to remove maven project and reimport anymore...

Comment: Can you please check if the issue persists with the latest one (2023.2.3)? How exactly you are building the Project (which Maven Lifecycle/Goal is used)? Would you be able to share your Project, its' pom.xml?

Comment: springboot project, use idea default build(right click main class -> run), haven't tried 2023.2.3,  I use single window to open multi-projects